# ASP.NET MVC post still goes through even though validation should block it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

If I do the following

ViewModel:

```
public class ToleranceInput{
    public decimal Tolerance{get;set;}
}
```

And in my views

AssignTolerances.cshtml

```
@model ToleranceInput

 @using (@Html.BeginForm("AssignTolerances", Tolerances", FormMethod.Post, new {@class="form-horizontal"}))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.Partial("_AssignOrEditTolerances", Model)

         <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit">
                <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Save
            </button>      
         </div>  
    }
```

_AssignOrEditTolerances.cshtml:

```
@model ToleranceInput

@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Tolerance)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Tolerance)
```

The standard MVC validation works correctly. When I type in letters (instead of numbers) it shows a red error message as it should. However, in the viewmodel if I change Tolerance to a nullable `decimal?` it does not work correctly. if I type a non-decimal such as 'asdf' in the textbox I see a quick flash of the red validation messsage when I hit the save button, but then the POST goes through and the [HttpPost] `AssignTolerances` method in my controller gets executed. Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Edit: I have just found the following link. Looks like the strings get converted to nulls and the workaround looks horrible: [Integer validation against non-required attributes in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334350/integer-validation-against-non-required-attributes-in-mvc)

Comment: I think you should provide some custom validation to your model property if you want it to be nullable. May be a Regex for decimal values should do the work. `[RegularExpression(@"^\-{0,1}\d+(.\d+){0,1}$)"]`

Comment: The post request still goes through by doing custom validation

Comment: The try with `[Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999"]`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Making `Tolerance` nullable displays "The field Tolerance must be a number." and prevents the submit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also considered adding the check in the controller action?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestPost(ToleranceInput model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And then simply add validation into your Model, such as the [Required] attribute