# Let a RegularExpression accept nothing or numbers

Tags: c#, regex

How do I let the `RegularExpression` accept nothing or only numbers.
At this moment it only accepts numbers. But if I don't enter anything it gives me the standard error: "The Seconds between refreshes field is required."

I want the user to be able to fill in nothing. (My application makes standard values.)

I couldn't find this on other questions. Only white spaces.

```
[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Test, ErrorMessage from RegularExpression")]
public int NumberOfSecondsBetweenRefresh { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Settings_Personal", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NumberOfSecondsBetweenRefresh)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NumberOfSecondsBetweenRefresh)

    <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />
}
```

Comment: What if you add `?` at the end? `"([1-9][0-9]*)?"`

Comment: Nope still getting the message that the field is required.

Comment: Besides Wiktor's comment, you could also make the int nullable with `int?` to make the distinction between no value (null) and a zero value clear.

Comment: Perhaps, you may need [a solution like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18336965/3832970).

Comment: Wow, stupid I didn't thought about that @Boris. I was going for the expressions. Thanks man, that worked!

Comment: Just for the next time, there is a pretty good online regext tester:

https://www.debuggex.com/

*I'm not releated to it, but I found it very useful*

Comment: It is not clear to me: does a mere `?` after `int` fix the whole problem?

Comment: Yes, first I was getting a standard error message because an `int` can't be null and has to be some kind of number. But I want to be able to send null to my controller (so standard values can be applied). So `int?` means that the `int` can be null.

Comment: @Nekeniehl, nice one. But I came along this one: https://regexr.com/?32t3r I like it way better because they explain the expression.

Comment: @NashCarp http://regex101.com is much better since it supports 4 regex flavors and provides regex debugging and code snippet generation features.

Comment: The problem with those is none support .Net regex, which is why I use LINQPad generally. regex101 is especially notable for having obscure Regex choices, I'm surprised it doesn't have Ruby. Also disappointed they don't support real Perl, but that could be very dangerous.